# Searching symbol patterns

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to use this awk script:

```
awk -v count=0 '/`),`/ { count++ } END { print count }' sample.sql
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:
awk: line 1: runaway regular expression /\),/ {..
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

The target is to count line with backticks and closing parenthese like:

```
INSERT INTO test (`id`, `Address`) VALUES (1,'Delhi'),(2,'Mumbai')
```

> Thanx @Tensibai.  I just added \ line to ),. and its works. My .sql
>   contain INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`nm`) VALUES
>   (1,'delhi'),(2,'mumbai'),(3,'chennai')...; SO, I did search for ),
>   with starting count=1. have anyone idea to where will be search better
>   to do count.?

Comment: What version `awk --version` ? Also im guessing this is in a pipeline and you have more single quotes hanging about ?

Comment: When I do the search for any word like INSERT then it runs and give me output. But, when I search for ), then it gives me error

Comment: Are those backticks supposed to be there ??? `'/\`),\`/`

Comment: Why do you use backticks in the regex ? the `)` has a meaning in regex, it should be escaped: `'/\),/ { count ++ }` should do

Comment: @Tensibai The `)` won't cause a syntax error though, the command should work .

Comment: @JID mine give a compile error (but using mawk, default on ubuntu)

Comment: @Tensibai Fair enough, I only tried on gawk to be fair! I did ask OP what version they were using but they didn't reply.

Comment: @Pranay di I understood correctly your problem (counting lines) or do you try to know how much values are in each line ?

Comment: I don't see any instance of `\`),\`` in your input.

Comment: @Tensibai Please see my edited part in question.

Comment: @Pranay see my edited answer wich should be what's you're looking for.

Comment: Hey guys :-( I am getting confuse that How to do search. It searching for line not for all letters.. I want to search all '),' in .sql file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you try to achieve (counting lines wich contain `),` ) this should do:

```
awk '/\(`.*`\)`/ { count++ } END { print count }' sample.sql
```

No need to initialize the variable, match a line containing

```
(` any text here `)
```

and increment a counter to be printed at end.

---

As I've a small doubt on the original question here is how to count the number of value in each line:

```
awk '/\(.*\),/ { n=split($0,a,"\),"); print n; ncount += n; count++;} END { print "Lines matched:",count,"total values:",ncount }'
```

Here for each line with more than one value ( match `(text inside),` ) split on `),` and get the number of values into variable `n`, then print `n`, sum the number of values and increment the number of lines matched.

At end print the lines matched and the total values found.

**Warning** this does not count the lines where only one value is given. (no `,` after the last ))

---

To avoid the warning above and to focus on `INSERT` statement only:

```
 awk '/INSERT.*\(.*\),*/ { n=split($0,a,"\)(,|\n)"); print n; count++;} END { print count }' /srv/db-backup-20-10-2014.sql
```

Adding INSERT as the starting word and an option on the split to split on a closing parenthese followed by a comma or newline.

Comment: Thanx I am eaxactly looking for that. Its work like charm. Thank you.

Comment: @Pranay I found a drawback too, this count the `PRIMARY_KEY (column),(column)` too, do you wish to count only on `INSERT` Statements ?

Comment: Yes In my .sql file only insert statement

Comment: Now onwords my .sql file contain.. INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`nm`) VALUES (1,'delhi'),... But, If in future it contain more than the column s present in this then It should work fine or not?

Comment: This code does not care, it just count the values parentheses, regardless of the number of field inside

Comment: Can we chat on mailID

Comment: If you have time then We can ping on mail pls

Comment: Ok please see my mail.. pratiksha0035@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more clear as to what you trying to achieve as far as I can understand is you are trying to get the count of lines present in the file sample.sql, that you can also achieve by using

```
awk -v count=0 '{ gsub("[^)]", ""); count++} END{print count}' sample.sql
```

Comment: The OP stated in the comments, the target is to count the number of line containing `)`

Comment: Yes but the .sql file contain. some what like...INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `Address`) VALUES (1,'Delhi'),(2,'Mumbai')....;

Comment: So I want to the rows that meance how many values (1,'Delhi')-> 1 then (2,'Mumbai')-> is two..like wise

Answer (score 0):

`awk` initializes an integer with `0` on it's first usage. If you want to count lines in a file containing `)`, you can simply use this:

```
awk '/\)/{c++} END {print c}' input
```

Comment: I think the want to count line with `),` on.

Comment: Count the ' ), ' this in whole file.